# Open external files with eclipse ---> Error: "The default workspace is in use or cannot be created"

Tags: eclipse, ide

I need to open certain files (.java, .js, .html ...) with eclipse but when I try to do it I get the following error:

"The default workspace is in use or cannot be created"

How can I solve? Thank you.

Comment: This is rather unclear, tell us exactly what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to import projects to meaningfully use your files.

Otherwise, you just get a, for example, .java or .class file that you cannot do anything.

If you are importing an existing project, check this link: https://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-import-a-java-project-into-eclipse-ide/

Another option is, copying and pasting your existing file in the workplace folder that eclipse points to. Then go into eclipse and create a new project with the exact same name. At this point, eclipse should recognize the project and show it in the left project explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

I have my project/s on Eclipse with obviously my workspace/s. If for example I have the ide open because I'm working on a workspace I can not open external files. I would like them instead to open up in my current work area.